# Using cURL to access Facebook-friends without Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I saw these apps on Facebook before that lets you monitor who defriends you. Unfortunately these were removed. Possibly because Facebook doesn't like to show "negative" stuff. So I'm trying to write a PHP-script to fetch all of my friends from Facebook, store them in a database and the next time I run the script and it fetches all of my friends, it will compare them with the ones already stored in the database.

Since I will be using this strictly locally, I don't want to create an application for it on Facebook and therefore I cannot use the Facebook API(since I don't have a key).

So how would I go about to get access to all of my friends?
I managed to use cURL to login to facebook and redirect me to http://www.facebook.com/friends/?everyone&ref=tn. Unfortunately it doesn't list everyone and on top of that, it's selected "Recently Interacted" by default. However, the selection of only friends names works perfectly.

How would I use cURL to:

1) Select "All Friends" from the dropdown list(I think it's done via JS or AJAX so I'm not sure how cURL handles that)

2) Be able to use cURL to somehow scroll through the different pages(all friends are paginated). Changing page is not done via URL(like &page=2, &page=3 and so on), it is either a POST-request or a JS or AJAX.

My current script looks like this:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$user_id    = '';
$user_email = "";
$user_pass  = "";

$fp = fopen("example.html", "w");
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php?&next=http://www.facebook.com/friends/?everyone&ref=tn');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($user_email).'&pass='.urlencode($user_pass).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_exec($ch);

// So we can view the facebook-page
include('example.html');

$html = file_get_html("example.html");
$count = 0;
$found = 0;

foreach( $html->find('a') as $link )
{

    $count++;
    if( strpos( $link, 'profile.php?id=' ) && !strpos( $link, $user_id ) && !strpos( $link->innertext, 'img' ) )
    {

        $found++;
        echo 'Link #' . $found . ': ' . $link->innertext;
        echo '<br />';

    }

}

echo $count . ' links found where ' . $found . ' links matched profile-links';
```

To test it you need to

1) Download simple_html_dom.php from: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

2) Create an empty file, example.html

3) Create an empty file, cookie.txt

4) And of course fill in the user_id, user_email and user_pass at the top with your values

Comment: It's not what you asked for, but I'd create an app and just turn off social discovery.  Getting around the application key will be very difficult, to say the least.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I tried that it was just sooo many things to fill in.. and it makes me scared. Not because of the many things but because it's so serious. If Facebook really doesn't want these kinds of apps to keep track of whenever someone defriends you then they might just shut it down -- and even worse, close my Facebook account. Perhaps I'm paranoid :P

Comment: cURL is not the way to go. You need to use something more complex like Watir. Also, this is against TOS.

Comment: "sooo many things to fill in"
You're kidding, right?

Comment: There's at least 20 things to fill in. Application URL, Application TOS, I don't have any of those. I'm running it off localhost and it will be a private app so no need for TOS. All of these fields are required. In any case, it's against the TOS apparently so I guess it's a no-go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is against the Facebook terms of service. You shouldn't try to do things that others have had apps deleted for. Please check out the terms of service [here](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php) for more details.

Comment: What exact point are you referring to?
The thing is that I *could* just aswell write it down manually - what's the difference if I do it with a script?

Comment: 3.2. You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our permission.

Comment: I realize you can do it manually and you obviously want to have it for private use, but the main issue is that you are asking how to do something that violates the terms of service. Sorry. You could totally do it with the API and if it only gets used by you it probably won't get deleted. Also, it would be much easier to do with the API and getting an API key is really painless process.

Comment: Let's say the app would get deleted, for arguments sake. Would it be likely to lead to a termination of my account? And is it possible to run applications from localhost if you do not post a "Application URL" at the application information??

Comment: It depends on the violation if you get banned or not, but I take my previous recommendation back. It turns out that defriend apps are direct violations of the facebook platform policy: "You must not circumvent (or claim to circumvent) our intended limitations on core Facebook features and functionality." @ https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ Sorry, I know many people want to see this but its just not allowed.

Comment: So basicaly.. if the function doesn't exist in Facebook, there should not be an app that mimic the functionality, correct?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Its basically saying that you can't use the Facebook Platform to augment the basic functionality of Facebook.

Comment: That sucks. Facebook is weird. It's my friendlist.. I *should* be allowed to do whatever I want with it. Ohwell. You didn't have to neg-rep me though :p. Thanks for the help in any case.